# Empty dump() output in Symfony CLI

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

I'm building a simple *Symfony-shell* script to test my Symfony app **on interactive mode**:

```
# bin/app_dev_cli.php

require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
// Initialize bundles and container
$kernel->boot();

// Useful global vars
$container = $kernel->getContainer();
$doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');
$em = $doctrine->getManager();
```

Later, opening PHP *interactive mode* and including the previous script I can do some tasks quickly:

```
/path/to/symfony/project$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

# Booting the Symfony-shell app
php > require 'bin/app_dev_cli.php';

# Check if one service has been registered successfully
php > dump( $container->has('some_service') );

# Test some service
php > dump( $container->get('some_service')->run($param) );

# Manage some entities and DB data flow
php > $apple = new AppBundle\Entity\Fruit('Apple');
php > $em->persist($apple);
php > $em->flush();

php > dump( $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Fluit')->findAll() );

# etc.
```

**The problem** here is that **the `dump()` function shows nothing**. I was expecting a colored command line output, however I tried this with `echo` or `var_dump()` and it works, but for *objects* mainly the output is dense and unreadable. In this direction the [VarDumper Component documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) says:

> By default, the output format and destination are selected based on your current PHP SAPI [...]
>     * On the command line (CLI SAPI), the output is written on STDOUT. [...]

That's not working for me by default and I'm sure that `PHP_SAPI` is `cli`. Besides, [I found a workaround](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/debug.html#dump-destination) setting `debug.dump_destination` to `php://stderr`, BUT:

```
# php interactive mode:
php > dump("test");
hp shell code on line 1: // <---- show the code line always
"test"
```

I don't like this output and neither change the config for this purpose only.

**Any thoughts what happens with the `dump()` function and why it shows nothing?** Thanks.

Comment: After migrating from 3.4 to 4.4, adding the missing file "package/debug.yaml" with php://stderr option fix the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, it looks like what you are trying to do is actually dependency injecting a specific handler into `VarDumper`

So the condition `null === self::$handler` is always false in the below reproduced snippet of that class code, and, thus, the dumper you expect for `'cli' === PHP_SAPI` is not set.

```
public static function dump($var)
{

    if (null === self::$handler) {
    /**       ^--- this one       **/
        $cloner = new VarCloner();
        $dumper = 'cli' === PHP_SAPI ? new CliDumper() : new HtmlDumper();
        self::$handler = function ($var) use ($cloner, $dumper) {
            $dumper->dump($cloner->cloneVar($var));
        };
    }
    return call_user_func(self::$handler, $var);
}
```

source: [Symfony/Component/VarDumper/VarDumper.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5129c4cf7e294b1a5ea30d6fec6e89b75396dcd2/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/VarDumper.php#L30)

Now, knowing this, your solution is as easy as just setting the handler of `VarDumper` back to `null`

Working code:

```
# bin/app_dev_cli.php
<?php
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->boot();

/** This line (plus the use statement on top) does what you want **/
VarDumper::setHandler(null);

// Useful global vars
$container = $kernel->getContainer();
$doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');
$em = $doctrine->getManager();
```

When run:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > require 'bin/app_dev_cli.php';
# bin/app_dev_cli.php 
php > dump('hi'); 
"hi"
```

Comment: Well, everything seems that the culprit is `DebugBundle`, who injects his handler first. In `prod` env `VarDumper::setHandler(null)` is needless :)